# How to see if a user is pressing on same location on screen for 2 seconds?

Tags: android, location, ondraw, seconds, ontouch

I have a simple custom view that has an onDraw and onTouchEvent methods. What I'd need is to somehow check if a user has been holding his finger on the same spot(Y coordinate) for more than 2 seconds.

**EDIT:** Added description and code.

What my simple custom view is doing is drawing a horizontal line underneath users finger. As you move up and down across the screen the horizontal line follows you. **What I'm trying to do is to raise a flag (boolean) if user has been holding finger on the same spot for 2 seconds** - in other words, if the line was held around some Y coordinate for 2 seconds.

```
public class RateView extends View {

float touchY = (getHeight() / 2);
boolean isPressed = false;
Paint paint = new Paint();

//Bunch of standard constructors

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
    paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.line));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //If pressed -> draw horizontal line
    if (isPressed) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, touchY, (canvas.getWidth()), touchY, paint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            isPressed = true;

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchY = motionEvent.getY();

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            isPressed = false;

            break;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a runnable in combination with a runnable to achieve this. You can run a Runnable which executes what you want after two seconds only if the view is still pressed AND if the y-coordinate during execution is within a range of the y-coordinate when the runnable was first started. The code will look something like this.

```
boolean mViewIsPressed = false;
float yCoordPrev;
float yCoordCurr;
Runnable runnable;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
    // MotionEvent object holds X-Y values
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        String text = "You click at x = " + event.getX() + " and y = " + event.getY();
        Log.d("debug-x: ", String.valueOf(event.getX()));
        Log.d("debug-y: ", String.valueOf(event.getY()));
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        yCoordPrev = event.getY();

        runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


                //Check if user is still holding down on the view
                if (mViewIsPressed) {
                    yCoordCurr = event.getY();

                    //Check if position that is being held down is the same (or within range) as 2 seconds ago
                    if ((yCoordCurr < yCoordPrev+10) && (yCoordCurr > yCoordPrev -10) ){
                        //Do what you want here after 2 seconds of pressing
                        Log.d("debugFireEvent: ", "fire");
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
        mViewIsPressed = true;


    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if(mViewIsPressed) {
            mViewIsPressed = false;
            yCoordCurr = event.getY();
            //Cancel the runnable because the user stopped pressing
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
        }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

You can play around with the range in the if statement in runnable, if `((yCoordCurr < yCoordPrev+10) && (yCoordCurr > yCoordPrev -10) )`, to be more precise but since fingers move a little even when the user is still pressing at the same spot, I think it is better to have a range.

Comment: Wow I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Just need a small tweak. A little bit of description what my view is doing: with my onDraw method I'm drawing a horizontal line underneath users finger so he can move it up and down and the line will also move due to ACTION_MOVE catching coords and sending to draw. What I want to achieve is if the user is holding the line around some Y coordinate for 2 seconds, an image pops. Would it work like that if I put your code in ACTION_MOVE instead?

Comment: I think you can apply the same logic except you'd have to keep track of whether the user moved his hand up or not. It would be more helpful and clear if you can provide some more code in your question. You may try using this logic and see if this works for you.